# Why is co_await for loop not shipped in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine, c++-ts

I've seen this code from cppcoro library from github repository:

```cpp
cppcoro::async_generator<int> ticker(int count, threadpool& tp)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    co_await tp.delay(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    co_yield i;
  }
}

cppcoro::task<> consumer(threadpool& tp)
{
  auto sequence = ticker(10, tp);
  for co_await (std::uint32_t i : sequence)
  {
    std::cout << "Tick " << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Wherein the `async_generator` yields a value while can `co_await` and the coroutine `consumer` has the `for co_await` wherein the equivalence of:

```cpp
for co_await (std::uint32_t i : sequence) {
  std::cout << "Tick " << i << std::endl;
}
```

is

```cpp
{
  auto&& __range = sequence;
  auto __begin   = co_await __range.begin();
  auto __end     = __range.end();
  for (; __begin != __end; co_await ++__begin) {
    std::uint32_t i = *__begin;
    std::cout << "Tick " << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

according to the Coroutine TS draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4775.pdf

What is the reason why `for co_await` is not shipped in C++20?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: just a snippet of code. I didn't intend to compile it.

Comment: [35. Remove for co_await statement.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0664r8.html#35)
`The wording for co_await statement makes assumptions of what future asynchronous generator interface will be. Remove it for now as not to constraint the design space for asynchronous generators.`